# Foreman fails to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Has anyone seen this? All of a sudden I can't start foreman and getting this error.

```
20:58:18 web.1 | started with pid 23100
20:58:19 web.1 | /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:33:in parse!': missing argument: -e (OptionParser::MissingArgument) 
20:58:19 web.1 | from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:283:inparse_options'
20:58:19 web.1 | from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:180:in options' 
20:58:19 web.1 | from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:54:inset_environment'
20:58:19 web.1 | from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:42:in initialize' 20:58:19 web.1 | from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:innew'
20:58:19 web.1 | from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in <top (required)>' 20:58:19 web.1 | from script/rails:6:inrequire'
20:58:19 web.1 | from script/rails:6:in `'
20:58:19 web.1 | exited with code 1
20:58:19 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

By the way, the manual startup works fine. Here's what I am running:

```
Rails 3.2.11
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
foreman (0.76.0)
thor (0.19.1)
dotenv (1.0.2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Somehow .env file with all the environment settings got deleted. Everything worked once I recreated the file.